# Conditional survival function in landmark analysis

Tags: survival, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, time-varying-covariate

In H.Putter & H.C. van Houwelingen's paper

["Understanding Landmarking and Its Relation with Time-Dependent Cox Regression"](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12561-016-9157-9)

the authors state that the conditional survival function, given $s<t$ and $X(s)$, is:

$S(t|s,X(s))=\mathbb{P}[T≥t|T≥s,X(s)]=\mathbb{E}[exp(−\int_s^th_0(u)e^{β(u)X(u)}du)|X(s)]$.

Could someone kindly show me the computational steps to end up with this formula? I can not see how to get the far right member of this stream of equalities.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from the basic relations among instantaneous hazards, cumulative hazards, and survival functions in the context of a proportional hazards model. See for example the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Hazard_function_and_cumulative_hazard_function) or these [course notes](https://grodri.github.io/glms/notes/c7s1).

Here, $h_0(u)e^{\beta(u)X(u)}$ is the instantaneous hazard at time $u$, given a proportional-hazard situation with baseline hazard $h_0(u)$ as a function of time, time-varying coefficients $\beta(u)$, and time-varying covariates $X(u)$.

The integral in the formula is related to the cumulative hazard $H(u)$. Starting from time 0, the cumulative hazard through time $t$ is

$$H(t) = \int_0^th_0(u)e^{β(u)X(u)}du $$

and that through time $s$ is

$$H(s) = \int_0^sh_0(u)e^{β(u)X(u)}du .$$

In general, the survival function can be written (see links above):

$$ S(u) = \exp[-H(u)]$$

So survival through time $t$ given survival through time $s$ is:

$$
\frac{S(t)}{S(s)} = \frac{\exp\left[-H(t)\right]}{\exp\left[-H(s)\right]} = \exp\left[-(H(t)-H(s))\right] $$
$$=\exp\left[−\int_s^th_0(u)e^{β(u)X(u)}du\right].$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Edm. Your explanation it's very clear, but what I cannot explain is tht expectation. With respect to which distribution is calculated? and why? could you kindly add some comments about that?

Comment: @MatteoPetrosino the expectation is over the members of the population of interest. They don't all necessarily have the same $X(u)$ values, for example, but the conditional survival of _each_ of them can be described as above. You then average over the population.

Comment: So, is it correct to say that we'll get $\mathbb{P}[T \geq t | T \geq s, X(\bar{s})] \approx 1/n \sum_{\bar{s} : x=X(\bar{s})} exp(-\int_{\bar{s}}^t h_0(u)e^{\beta (u) x}du)$  $\forall \bar{s}, t>\bar{s}$ ?

Comment: @MatteoPetrosino that assumes fixed $x=X(s)$ for all times after $s$. That is what's done in landmark analysis that ignores changes in $X(u)$ after time $s$ but that's not what the formula in your question describes. The linked paper assesses the difference between the actual conditional survival (the formula in your question) and the approximation assuming fixed $x=X(s)$ for all times after $s$ (as in your comment).